# Is this autocorrelation formula correctly programmed?

Tags: c#, math, formula, equation

I am trying to implement a pitch detection algorithm from a paper, but the level of math in the paper is a few notches too advanced for me... for now.

I just want to make sure that I've understood it correctly.

I also added comment to my code that asks a question which confuses me.

The paper can be found here: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0124/09d447691fd74c49bc407b3818b4617641b2.pdf

And the formula can be found on the upper right side of the second page.
[image]

My code looks like this.

```
public int L = 0.1f;

public float calcAutocorrelation(float[] frame)

    int N = frame.Length; //frame size

    float result = 0f;
    for (var n = 0; n < N; n++){
        result += frame[n] * frame[n + L] //in programming this is not possible as L is a float but formula says this is needed???

        /* I could cast the L to an INT type but the paper states
         * that L should range between 0 and 1, and in-code we'll
         * probably end up with L rounded to 0 most of the time.
         */

    }

    return result;
}
```

What have I missed and what could be done better?

**EDIT**
Fixed and simplified the code.

```
public int Lag = 1;

public float calcAutocorrelation(float[] frame)

    int N = frame.Length; //frame size

    float result = 0f;
    for (var n = 0; n < N; n++)
        result += frame[n] * frame[n + Lag]

    return result;
}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

So apparently the result sometimes end up as a `NaN` type, which I have a hard time figuring out.

I hacked together a simple solution like the code below, but that's not really a fix, it's just a bypass which would not give the correct result desired.

I tested my code with a small frame of 16 `floats` and the frame contains no `NaN` values what so ever. Either I'm stupid or I'm stupid because I can not for the life of me figure out what's going on.

Test Frame:

```
frame[0]   : 0
frame[1]   : 0
frame[2]   : 96
frame[3]   : 185
frame[4]   : 0
frame[5]   : 0
frame[6]   : 0
frame[7]   : 185
frame[8]   : 0
frame[9]   : 0
frame[10]  : 192
frame[11]  : 184
frame[12]  : 0
frame[13]  : 0
frame[14]  : 0
frame[15]  : 184
```

Code:

```
public int lag = 1;

public float calcAutocorrelation(float[] frame){

    float result = 0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < frame.Length - lag; i++){

        float a = frame[i];
        if ( float.isNaN(a) )
            a = 0;

        int b_idx = (i + lag);
        float b = frame[b_idx];
        if ( float.isNaN(b) )
            b = 0;

        result += a * b;

    }

    return 0f - result; //just inverting the results for my purposes. Doesn't really affect the end goal.
}
```

**QUESTION**
So how come `b` is `NaN` when `b_idx = 7` and `frame[7]` is `185`?
This absolutely boggles my mind!

Here's a screenshot of what's happening on my end:
[image]

---

**EDIT 3**

Found the problem regarding the `NaN` issue.
It seems to not be a problem at all (I think) and can be handled with a check&correct using `float.isNaN()`.

The reason the frame is casted as a byte array is because of how the underlying audio library `NAudio` handles the conversion.

Read about it here: http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2008/06/wavebuffer-casting-byte-arrays-to-float.html

So even though it shows up as a byte array, each value will be casted to a float correctly when working with it.

Weird, but true. Personally, that type of coding should be illegal by law, jk.

So, everything seems to be working (I think?), how is my implementation of the formula performing?

Well, the paper states the following at page 6 under Fig 6:

> One of the experiments conducted was applying the PDA on /a/
>   utterances from the KayPENTAX Elemetrics voice database consists of 50
>   normal voices and 100 functional and organic voice disorders.

I recorded my own `/a/` vowel and gave it a run, and this is what is plotted on my screen:

[image]

> [image]
>
> Fig 1a on page 2 of the paper

Comparing my results to Fig 1a on page 2 of the paper we can see strong similarities, but I am still not sure if I've implemented the formula correctly, because the formula I want to implement should resemble figure 1b or 1c.

I think the issue now is where the formula variable `i` should be in terms of code.

The paper states on page two the following:

> i = The first sample inside a frame n

so... hmmm...

Comment: `n + L` truncates down to `n` since `L = 0.1f`. Did you mean to write `L = 1.0f`?

Comment: pretty sure 2nd page says L ranges "from zero to  the number of samples per frame minus one", in particular - is integral

Comment: @YuriFeldman aah yes that is correct I must have confused that with something else.

Comment: And why is this voted as off-topic? It's perfectly on-topic. It's about programming.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I misread and misinterpreted the paper, and the type of L was an INT in the first place. you are sort of correct. I meant to write L = 1;

Comment: Is this C#? You should include the tag.

Comment: In the last loop `n + Lag` will be `N - 1 + Lag`, which means in your case `N`, therefore, you will have an out of bounds error.

Comment: @Andrew correct, C#.
How come it would be `N - 1 + Lag`?
The `N - 1` part is handled by the loop initialization at `..; n < N; ...`. Specifically the `<`, unless it would have been `<=`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: `n` will be `N - 1` in the last loop, so `n + Lag` (`n + 1`) will be `N`. I think your condition should be `; n < N - 1;`, as that's what you have above the sigma symbol.

Comment: But is `frame` an array of floats or bytes? How are you calling `formula_1`? Note that `a` also has a weird value (E-44!) instead of 0.

Comment: @Andrew I updated the question which explains what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to fix the condition in your `for` loop, so in the last cycle, it doesn't go out of bounds:

```
public int Lag = 1;

public float CalcAutocorrelation(float[] frame)
{
    int N = frame.Length; //frame size

    float result = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < N - Lag; n++)
        result += frame[n] * frame[n + Lag];

    return result;
}
```

(Note I've changed the `for` condition).

If you are getting NaN errors, you can check that like this:

```
for (int n = 0; n < N - Lag; n++)
{
    result += frame[n] * frame[n + Lag];
    if (float.IsNaN(result))
    {
        var v1 = frame[n];
        var v2 = frame[n + Lag];
    }
}
```

Just place a breakpoint inside that `if` and see what's going on. That should help you find a problem inside your array. Once that's fixed, you can remove that check and restore the code above.

Comment: I tried this, but I my final results are invalid because of `frame[n]` and `frame[n + lag]` sometimes being `NaN` which I have a hard time figuring out why. They are both valid numbers, but for some reason end up as `NaN`

Comment: Well, that must be something really easy to debug. I just updated the code to handle that.

Comment: I did something similar already, but I don't think that it actually solves the problem. The real quesion would be `why is there a NaN in the first place when the frame contains no NaN's what so ever?`. I've updated my question to explain this.